# Insert data into (col 30, row 1)

Tags: c#, sql-server, insert

```
con.Open(); 

SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

string[] col = {
                   "name","dr", "WBC", "Lympho", "Mono", "Gran", "RBC",
                   "Hb", "PCV", "Platelet", "ESR","BloodGroupRh", 
                   "Striglycride","SChol","SHDL","SLDL","BloodUrea",
                   "SCreatenin","SUA","SCa","RBSugar","HBA1c",
                   "SGOT","SGPT","ALP","TSB","SerumBhCG","Myoglobin",
                   "CK","Trobonin","CRP","AntiCCP","STyphoied IgG",
                   "STyphoied IgM", "RoseBengal","me","HCV","HBS"
               };
Control[] val = { 
                    textBox1, comboBox1, txt1, txt2, txt3, txt4, txt5, txt6,
                    txt7, txt8, txt9, txt10, txt11, txt12, txt13, txt14, txt15, 
                    txt16, txt17, txt18, txt19, txt20, txt21, txt22, txt23, txt24,
                    txt25, txt26, txt27, txt28, txt29, txt30, txt31, txt32, txt33,
                    txt34, txt35, txt36
                };

for (int x = 0; x < col.Length;x++)
{
    cmd.CommandText += "INSERT INTO [Table] (" + col[x] +") VALUES('" + val[x].Text +"')";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
} 
      
con.Close();
```

As code showing I have approx 35 columns I tried to insert it by using for loop, but when i run this code he insert 35 rows next with many null values in cells

Like this:

[my table after run this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9oVNp.png)

I want to put all 35 columns values into one row.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should ***NEVER EVER*** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: @marc_s thanks , is there a way to do that ? insert data into 35 columns and one row..

Comment: You need to create a single insert query using for loop and then execute it. And yes parametrized query is highly recommended.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya. Thank you, can you please give me the single insert using for loop syntax.. and how can i use parametrized query in for loop

Comment: 'Insert' creates a new row. Use 'Update' ...'where' to update values in an existing row. Your code is creating 35 'Insert' statements which creates 35 rows. Hopefully, you realize that you're creating 35 transactions instead of 1, which increases network traffic and database server load.

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(yourConnectionString);
            using (con)
            {
                con.Open();
                string[] col = {
                       "name","dr", "WBC", "Lympho", "Mono", "Gran", "RBC",
                       "Hb", "PCV", "Platelet", "ESR","BloodGroupRh",
                       "Striglycride","SChol","SHDL","SLDL","BloodUrea",
                       "SCreatenin","SUA","SCa","RBSugar","HBA1c",
                       "SGOT","SGPT","ALP","TSB","SerumBhCG","Myoglobin",
                       "CK","Trobonin","CRP","AntiCCP","STyphoied IgG",
                       "STyphoied IgM", "RoseBengal","me","HCV","HBS"
                   };
                Control[] val = {
                        textBox1, comboBox1, txt1, txt2, txt3, txt4, txt5, txt6,
                        txt7, txt8, txt9, txt10, txt11, txt12, txt13, txt14, txt15,
                        txt16, txt17, txt18, txt19, txt20, txt21, txt22, txt23, txt24,
                        txt25, txt26, txt27, txt28, txt29, txt30, txt31, txt32, txt33,
                        txt34, txt35, txt36
                    };

                string col_query = null;
                string columns_in_query = null;
                for (int x = 0; x < col.Length; x++)
                {
                    col_query += x < col.Length - 1 ? +"@" + col[x] + ","+ :+"@" + col[x];
                    columns_in_query += x < col.Length - 1 ? col[x] +","+ : col[x];

                }
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into Table(" + columns_in_query + ") values(" + col_query + ")", con);
                for (int x = 0; x < col.Length; x++)
                   {
                    string value="";
                    if(val[x] is TextBox){
                       value=((TextBox)val[x]).Text.Trim();
                    }
                    if(val[x] is ComboBox){
                       value=((ComboBox)val[x]).SelectedItem.ToStrin().Trim();
                    }
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + col[x], value);
                }

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
```

Comment: error `ExecuteNonQuery: CommandText property has not been initialized`

Comment: Use using connection block, it will close connection as needed itself. See updated answer.

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: error again, I know my idea well, but i dont want use `insert into [Table] (name, dr, WBC,...., HBS) values(@name, @dr, @WBC, ....., @HBS);` its anoying and many colums should carry data for one patient, i know i can do it by using for loop but i cant see it yet

Comment: `throw new notimplement` or same like this

Comment: ok you also have different controls in array Control[] Cast it to respective control when getting values.

Answer (score -1):

```
con.Open(); 

SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

string[] col = {
                   "name","dr", "WBC", "Lympho", "Mono", "Gran", "RBC",
                   "Hb", "PCV", "Platelet", "ESR","BloodGroupRh", 
                   "Striglycride","SChol","SHDL","SLDL","BloodUrea",
                   "SCreatenin","SUA","SCa","RBSugar","HBA1c",
                   "SGOT","SGPT","ALP","TSB","SerumBhCG","Myoglobin",
                   "CK","Trobonin","CRP","AntiCCP","STyphoied IgG",
                   "STyphoied IgM", "RoseBengal","me","HCV","HBS"
               };
Control[] val = { 
                    textBox1, comboBox1, txt1, txt2, txt3, txt4, txt5, txt6,
                    txt7, txt8, txt9, txt10, txt11, txt12, txt13, txt14, txt15, 
                    txt16, txt17, txt18, txt19, txt20, txt21, txt22, txt23, txt24,
                    txt25, txt26, txt27, txt28, txt29, txt30, txt31, txt32, txt33,
                    txt34, txt35, txt36
                };

for (int x = 0; x < col.Length;x++)
{
    cmd.CommandText += "INSERT INTO [Table] (" + col[x] +") VALUES('" + val[x].Text +"')";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
} 
      
con.Close();
```

Comment: This is **just as bad** as the original question and **WIDE OPEN** to SQL injection ... this is horrible "advice" .....

Comment: code-only answers provide little opportunity for learning or guidance - which is why they are highly discouraged. And as already noted it is still as flawed as the original.

Comment: this actully my code, whenn you run it you will get 35 rows with many null values in other columns and cells

Answer (score -1):

```
string[] col = {
    "name", "dr", "WBC", "Lympho", "Mono", "Gran", "RBC",
    "Hb", "PCV", "Platelet", "ESR", "BloodGroupRh",
    "Striglycride", "SChol", "SHDL", "SLDL", "BloodUrea",
    "SCreatenin", "SUA", "SCa", "RBSugar", "HBA1c",
    "SGOT", "SGPT", "ALP", "TSB", "SerumBhCG", "Myoglobin",
    "CK", "Trobonin", "CRP", "AntiCCP", "STyphoied IgG",
    "STyphoied IgM", "RoseBengal", "me", "HCV", "HBS"
                   };
Control[] val = {
    textBox1, comboBox1, txt1, txt2, txt3, txt4, txt5, txt6,
    txt7, txt8, txt9, txt10, txt11, txt12, txt13, txt14, txt15,
    txt16, txt17, txt18, txt19, txt20, txt21, txt22, txt23, txt24,
    txt25, txt26, txt27, txt28, txt29, txt30, txt31, txt32, txt33,
    txt34, txt35, txt36
};

List < string > values = new List<string>();
foreach(Control c in val)
{
    if (c.GetType().Name == "TextBox")
         values.Add(((TextBox)c).Text);
    else if (c.GetType().Name == "ComboBox")
         values.Add(((ComboBox)c).Text);     // or get value whatever you want
}


cmd.CommandText += "INSERT INTO [Table] (" + string.Join(",", col) + ") VALUES('" + string.Join("','", values.ToArray()) + "')";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Please add some explantation text to your code

Comment: The controls also includes ComboBox

Comment: // just check controls before get values
foreach(Control c in val)
{
    if (c.GetType().Name == "TextBox")
           values.Add(((TextBox)c).Text);
    else if (c.GetType().Name == "ComboBox")
           values.Add(((ComboBox)c).Text);
}